# Prisma connectOrCreate unique constraints

Tags: prisma, supabase

I have a database of `Users`, `Lots` and `LotAnalysis` (simply an association of user with lot and some metadata).

1. I want to create a `Lot` if none found and create a `lotAnalysis` associated with user and new `Lot`.
2. IF there is a `Lot` update it by adding a `LotAnalysis` with this new user
3. OR if `LotAnalysis` for this `Lot` and `User` is found then do nothing.

What I have so far:

```
export default async function handle(req: any, res: any) {
  const { session, street } = req.body;

const foundLot = await prisma.lot.findFirst({
      where: {
        address: street.formatted_address
      }
    })

    if (foundLot) {
      const result = await prisma.lot.upsert({
          where: {
            address: street.formatted_address
          },
          create: {
              address: street.formatted_address,
              analysis: {
                connectOrCreate: {
                  where: {
                    userId_lotId: {
                      userId: session.user.id,
                      lotId: foundLot.id,
                    } 
                  },
                    create: {
                      user: { 
                        connect: {
                          email: session.user.email 
                        }
                      },
                      role: "CLIENT"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
          update: { 
              address: street.formatted_address,
              analysis: {
                connectOrCreate: {
                  where: {
                    userId_lotId: {
                      userId: session.user.id,
                      lotId: foundLot.id,
                    } 
                  },
                    create: {
                      user: { 
                        connect: {
                          email: session.user.email 
                        }
                      },
                      role: "CLIENT"
                    }
                  }
                }
          }
        })
        res.json(result)
    } else {
      const result = await prisma.lot.create({
        data: {
            address: street.formatted_address,
            analysis: {
                  create: {
                    user: { 
                      connect: {
                        email: session.user.email 
                      }
                    },
                    role: "CLIENT"
                  }
                }
              }
      })
      res.json(result)
    };
```

The pertinent parts of my schema are as follows:

```
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime? @map("email_verified")
  stripeId      String?    @unique
  isSubscribed  Boolean?   @default(false)
  image         String?
  createdAt     DateTime?
  updatedAt     DateTime?
  social        Json?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  lots          Lot[]
  lotAnalysis LotAnalysis[]
}

model Lot {
  id            Int     @unique @default(autoincrement()) @id
  address       String  @unique
  latitude      Float   
  longitude     Float   
  apn           String
  acreage       Float
  zoneType      String
  zoneDescription     String
  geometry      Json?
  zone          Json?

  // Relation fields
  enquiry User[]
  analysis LotAnalysis[]
}

model LotAnalysis {
  role      UserRole

  // Relation Fields
  userId    String
  lotId     Int     @unique @default(autoincrement())
  price     Float?
  results   LotResult?
  user      User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  lot       Lot @relation(fields: [lotId], references: [id])

  @@id([userId, lotId])
}
```

But I get the error

```
Unique constraint failed on the fields: (`lotId`)
```

Does that mean LotId shouldn't be unique?
Is there a cleaner way of doing this like pulling the new lotId into the `connectOrCreate` instead of checking initially with `foundLot` function ?
Is there a cleaner way to do this?